# Reset all files after reboot

Tags: linux, dd

I have a little question.

It is possible to reset all files of the system to the saved one?

I thought about saving state with dd to other disk, then create "man in the middle" so after boot it will flash this file into disk, but maybe there are better solutions?

Comment: Use filesystem snapshots.

Comment: This is easiest done in a virtual machine using snapshots.

Comment: and is there any solution without using virtual machine? i need to do it on normal machine (it will be reseting after tests)

Comment: Another easy way is to use a **live system**. If you clone from a linux iso file (which is usually a hybrid iso file) to a USB pendrive or DVD disk, you can boot the computer into a live system. You or other people can run things, install programs, save files etc, but after reboot everything will be back to what was created, when you cloned the system from the iso file. (It is also possible to clone from the iso file to an internal (SATA) drive and get the same behaviour.)

Comment: nice! is there any easy program like "create live system from your disk"?

Comment: Have a look at [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). If you are running Ubuntu, an Ubuntu community flavour, Debian, or a linux re-spin, that is based on those distros, you can install mkusb via the PPA. Otherwise you can install a simpler version, for example via a tarball. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation).

Comment: If you want to create live system from an installed system, you have a more difficult task. Maybe the following link can help, [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)